# A Puzzling Cafe Parfait

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, metapuzzles

> The Puzzle Cafe is famous for it's delicious parfaits, however, they come with a catch. To eat each layer, you have to solve the puzzle in the layer before it! After hearing all the rave reviews, I have to try one for myself, but the puzzles have me stumped!

*Use the first layer as a key to solve the second layer, which can then be used to solve the puzzle.*

---

**First Layer**:

NO = 2

YOU = 6

IRE = 3

IRELAND = 8

ABACUS = 10

---

**Second Layer**:

JILL

LIE

BALL

---

**PUZZLE**:

> d j j k p x g g w s u t z g s c g x k o j

---

**HINT**:

> There are a lot of board games lying around the cafe...

(Google is necessary)

Comment: Is NO = 14 supposed to be NO = 2?

Comment: If this is what I think it is, YOU and ABACUS are also wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the solution has something to do with

> scrabble

Which is supported by the first and second hints, as

> In scrabble, certain letters are worth certain points: Q = 10, Z = 10, A = 1, K = 5

'First Layer'

> Every word is equal to its score in Scrabble. For example, ABACUS = 1 + 3 + 1 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 10

'Second Layer'

> Using the same strategy, JILL = 11, LIE = 3 and BALL = 6

'Puzzle'

> Turning the numbers from the second layer into the letters "KCF" and using that as a key for the Vigenére cipher on the puzzle, we get "The answer is open sesame".

Comment: You're right about the scrabble part, I just accidentally messed up the word scores in the first layer. They're fixed now.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I was using a 'Words With Friends' letter score table so the whole thing had to be fixed.